# preg_replace to match all match in string even after first replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-match-all

This outputs:

```
$san_field = 'sometext PROS sometext sometext1234 CALEND 2007 RIT';
$pattern = '/(\s|^|- |--)(?:CALEND|2007|CALEND 2007 RIT)(--| -|\s|$)/i';
echo preg_replace($pattern, ' ', $san_field)

>> sometext PROS sometext sometext1234 2007 RIT
```

I'd like to replace `CALEND 2007 RIT` instead of `CALEND` which is the first match found on `$san_field`.
I know I can do this way:

```
$san_field = 'sometext PROS sometext sometext1234 CALEND 2007 RIT';
$pattern = '/(\s|^|- |--)(?:CALEND 2007 RIT|CALEND|2007)(--| -|\s|$)/i';
echo preg_replace($pattern, ' ', $san_field)

>> sometext PROS sometext sometext1234
```

but is there a more correct and practical way, because I will insert those pattern into an array which will be quite large...

Answer (score 2):

How about putting these patterns to an array, sorting that array by length (so longer text is checked first) and build up your regex afterwards?

```
$replace = ["2007", "CALEND", "CALEND 2007 RIT"];
usort($replace, function($a, $b){
    return strlen($b) - strlen($a);
});
$san_field = 'sometext PROS sometext sometext1234 CALEND 2007 RIT';
$pattern = '/(\s|^|- |--)(?:'.(implode('|', $replace)).')(--| -|\s|$)/i';
echo preg_replace($pattern, ' ', $san_field)
```

Additionally, it would be a good idea to `preg_quote` these values, just in case you put some special characters in.

```
foreach($replace as &$item) {
    $item = preg_quote($item);
}
```

Comment: This is what I will do as written in my question. But if `CALEND` comes before `CALEND 2007 RIT` into the array then what I expect won't work. Thank you for preg_quote, I will do that

Comment: How about sorting the array by length?

Comment: Not a bad idea, I'm just thinking if this "really working" or there are some situation which aren't working

Comment: I can't think about any case where this wouldn't work.

Comment: Note that your custom usort function doesn't work with multibyte strings and is uneeded since you can use `rsort($replace, SORT_STRING | SORT_FLAG_CASE);`

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is called a **negative look ahead assertion** in [PCRE](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) (or check out the [PCRE cheat sheet](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse190m/12sp/cheat-sheets/php-regex-cheat-sheet.pdf) for easier reading), which tells the engine to look for something like `'CALEND'` as long as it's not followed directly by `' 2007 RIT'`, in your case.

```
$san_field = 'sometext PROS sometext sometext1234 CALEND 2007 RIT';
$pattern = '/(\s|^|- |--)(CALEND(?! 2007 RIT)|2007|CALEND 2007 RIT)(--| -|\s|$)/i'
echo preg_replace($pattern, ' ', $san_field)
```

Which gives you...

> sometext PROS sometext sometext1234

Comment: That would match & replace "2007"

Comment: Yes, it would. That was in their original regular expression. Wasn't mentioned as a part of the problem so for all I know they want that.

Comment: Also, I think it would be quite an overkill, if you'd have to match all similar strings, if you have more of then. Nice answer though, +1

Comment: I don't see how that's overkill. One does have to remember the epic quote "*I had a problem so I used a regex... now I have two problems*" though.

Comment: @Perocat that's not a problem. That's an opportunity. If the values are not dynamically changing then it's trivial to compile them once into your regular expression using `implode`, for example, and never have to worry about it again. If, however, these values change dynamically then it's still quite trivial to compile them dynamically. If what you're really after is simple sub-string search and replace then perhaps you don't need a regular expression at all, but something like `str_replace` instead? Maybe the real problem is that you haven't yet fully understood your problem?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have an array with `strings = array('stuff1', 'stuff2', 'stuff3', 'stuff1 stuff2', 'stuff2 stuff3'); all those values can start with `' '|- |--` and terminate with `--| -|' '`, so the problem is that I cannot use this with `str_replace`. In addition to that, str_replace start from the first array member to the last. So if `stuff2 stuff3` comes after `stuff2`, then the `stuff2` will be replaced instead of `stuff2 stuff3`

Comment: @Perocat Uhh, no it won't. Also nothing in your regex here actually cares about what comes before or after the things you're trying to replace. Your use case is perfect for `str_replace`. I'm smelling [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) all over this question. The real question is why on earth do you need both `'stuff1'`, `'stuff2'`, **and** `'stuff1 stuff2'` as independent substring searches? Because that's all you're really doing here is a sub-string search.

Comment: Yes, I get it. Your examples are bad and don't depict your real problem, but again [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)